# Convert a .vmx file for use on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, vmware-vmdk

I've got a virtual machine that I'd like to have running as an EC2 instance.  Is there any way to simply convert a .vmx to an EC2 image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon now offers this service. Download a tool and it will create an AMI and upload the disk images.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/

Answer (score 2):

A vmx file is simply a descriptor for the vmware virtual machine. The VMDK is what you will need to convert.

Gareth's first link is a good tutorial on how to convert a VMDK->AMI, but you WILL have to change your kernel, and then you will have to bundle the image. The whole process is described on this link: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/amazon-ec2.html

Alternatively, you can talk to a vcloud provider about uploading your VM without any conversion: http://vcloud.vmware.com

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this specific situation myself, but here is a [useful link](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/9/1/creating-an-new-ec2-ami-from-within-vmware-or-from-vmdk-files) that should help you out.

Since this article was written, Amazon has introduced the ability to run a custom kernel, which may help if the kernel used on your VM is not one of the standard EC2 kernels (I'm assuming you're using Linux here).  See [this link](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/07/use-your-own-kernel-with-amazon-ec2.html) for more info.